# In WebStorm 2016, how do I rename rename an ID or Class value across all files

Tags: javascript, html, ide, webstorm

In WebStorm 2016 (or any version), I want to be able to change the name of a class or ID and have IDE automatically rename any uses across open files.

For example,

Project
  -src-
       main.js
       lib.js
  index.html

Inside index.htm.

`<div id="foo">...</div>`

And inside main.js

`var myElem = $('#foo');`

If I place the mouse cursor on 'foo' inside the  attribute, and select Refactor-->Rename, the rename dialog comes up.

(pretend the text to be replaced is 'foo')
[image: screenshot of Rename dialog]

The only option is to search in comments and strings.

This will result in renaming all of the uses of that name in the current file (index.html), but not any uses in the main.js or main.css files.

Similarly, performing the rename refactor in the .js file won't change the class or ID attributes in the .html file, or the class selector in the .css file.

I can perform a global "Replace in Path" on the string, but this is much different than a refactoring.

Is what I'm asking not possible in WebStorm or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`shift+ctrl+R`

[Cheatsheet for webstorm](https://www.shortcutfoo.com/app/dojos/webstorm-phpstorm-win/cheatsheet)

Comment: This answer is a keyboard shortcut for the "Search/Replace in Path" It simply provides an alternative method to do what is already described in the question. It does nothing to actually address or answer the question.